# Setting user permissions for a directory mounted in /etc/fstab

Tags: permissions, mount, ext4, fstab

My embedded Linux system is using an admin user account to make some restricted administration tasks. The home directory for that user is /mnt/foo. That directory is the mount point for a partition mounted by /etc/fstab on boot:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p6  /mnt/foo      ext4    defaults           0       0
```

The problem is with permissions for that /mnt/foo directory:

```
$ ls -ld /mnt/foo/
drwxr-xr-x   16 root     root          4096 Mar 23 07:54 /mnt/foo/
```

This permissions don't allow the admin user to create/write any file:

```
$ pwd
/mnt/foo
$ touch hello
touch: hello: Permission denied
```

This problem can be easily fixed setting 777 permissions to /mnt/foo in rcS startup script:

```
$ chmod 777 /mnt/foo
```

But I don't like this solution. I have tried setting different options in the fstab (gid=admin,uid=admin,umask=000), but it seems these mount options are not supported by ext4 filesystems.

Is the rcS startup script the only feasible way to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default value in the /etc/fstab entry line:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p6  /mnt/foo      ext4    defaults           0       0
```

to become

```
/dev/mmcblk1p6  /mnt/foo      ext4    file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 0       0
```

or whatever the permissions you want to give